# Python loop for egyptian fractions

Tags: loops, python-3.x, fractions

So i made a python3 program that gives the egyptian fractions of a normal fraction.

```
fraction = (int(input())/int(input()))

i = 1
while True:
    if fraction > (1/i):
        print(i)
        fraction = fraction - (1/i)
    i += 1
```

Of course now it works but the loop is never going to end,
what can i do to end it?

I came up with something, but this doesn't work.

```
if fraction.numerator == 1:
   break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have three suggestions.

- Use the `fractions` module, because floating point numbers will not give the exact precision you require.
- make your `while` loop terminate when the fraction is zero.
- change your `if` condition to be ">=" instead of ">".

```
from fractions import Fraction

f = Fraction(int(input()), int(input()))

i = 1
while f > 0:
    if f >= Fraction(1,i):
        print(i)
        f -= Fraction(1,i)
    i += 1
```